# IF EXISTS Part of Query not being executed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that inserts all records from a table into another table if it exists in the database. I've created a temp table that isn't in the specified db, but it's still being inserted into the other table.

```
IF (Exists (Select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'sch' and table_name = 'table21'))

Begin
    select * 
    into #table31
    from #testtable
End
```

Even though table `#testtable` doesn't exist in the expected dbo, the rows are still being added into #table31

Comment: Your temporary table might not exist, but `sch.table31` would seem to.

Comment: `#testtable` won't be created in the connected databases `dbo` schema. `#testtable` is a temporary table and will be created in `tempdb`. You won't see it in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects.

Comment: `#testtable` never exists in any database other than `tempdb`, and this query would not execute successfully if it didn't exist. Batch compilation means this will not produce an error until and unless the `if` branch is actually taken.

Comment: "Deferred Compilation" and "Statement Level Compilation" not "Batch Compilation"

Answer (score 0):

Change your existence test to:

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table31' ,N'U) is not null ...